# Não insere informacoes no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde,
Estou tentando inserir dados em um banco de dados e tenho como retorno a mensagem de erro: "Nao foi possivel cadastrar o usuario".

Estou usando o software Xamp, estando instalado o Apache e o Mysql.

O codigo é o seguinte:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Adicao Usuario Banco de Dados</title>

</head>

<body>

    <?php

    echo "<h1>ADICAO DE USUARIO</h1>";
    $conexao_bd = mysql_connect("localhost");

    if(!$conexao_bd) {

        echo "<p><b>Não foi possível conectar ao Banco de Dados</b></p>";
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    else {
          mysql_select_db("db_hotel",$conexao_bd);
          $retorno = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(Nome_Usuario,Senha_Acesso) VALUES('ADMIN','M45T3R')");
        if(!$retorno)
          echo "<h2>Nao foi possivel cadastrar o usuario!</h2>";
        else
          echo "<h2>Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!</h2>";
        }
    mysql_close($conexao_bd);

    ?>

</body>
```

Caso possam me ajudar, desde já agradeco....

Comment: Mostre o que tem dentro de '$retorno'. Da um var_dump($retorno). Possivelmente seja erro de conexão com seu bd.

Comment: Olá @Walter. Apanhe o erro com o código `echo(mysqli_error($conexao_bd));` no `if(!$retorno)` e coloque na sua questão.

Comment: Troque `echo "<h2>Nao foi possivel cadastrar o usuario!</h2>";` por `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: Qual versão do PHP você está usando?

Answer (score 0):

O *mysql_connect* Abre uma conexão com um servidor MySQL. Tente adicionar os parâmetros usuário e senha.
Exemplo:

```
$conexao_bd = mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha');
```

Como você está utilizando o xampp, você pode verificar qual usuário está atrelado ao localhost, a seguir iremos verificar onde encontrar o usuário e senha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que neste exemplo o **usuário** do **localhost** é o **root** e não temos senha.
Ou seja, o código de abertura de conexão com o banco ficaria:

```
$conexao_bd = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //host, usuario, senha vazia
```

Comment: Pessoal boa noite,

Comment: Obrigado pelas informacoes. Segui as dicas que vcs. deram e agora está ok. Vou continuar com os estudos aqui... Muito bacana